# preserve format of node body

Tags: views, theming, entities

for output display I used http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/accordion.html

**I have the following code**:

```
 <section id="main-content">
<dl class="row accordion" data-accordion>
<h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;"><b>About Us</b></h2><br/>
<?php foreach ($view->result as $key => $value) {?>
<img class="media-object" src="<?php print $GLOBALS['base_path']."sites/default/files/about/thumbnails/".$value->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_about_us_image['und'][0]['filename'];?>" alt="">
    <h2><?php echo $value->node_title;?></h2>
  <dd class="accordion-navigation">
    <a href="#pane<?php print $key;?>">
    <?php print $value->_field_data['nid']['entity']->body['und'][0]['summary'];?>...</a>
    <div id="pane<?php print $key;?>" class="content">
     <?php print $value->_field_data['nid']['entity']->body['und'][0]['value'];?></a>
    </div>
  </dd>
  <hr>
  <?php } ?>
</dl>
</section>
```

I want to preserve the format `HTML`  of

```
<?php print $value->_field_data['nid']['entity']->body['und'][0]['summary'];?>
```

and

```
<?php print $value->_field_data['nid']['entity']->body['und'][0]['value'];?>
```

How Can I achieve this with Drupal 7?

Comment: Could you explain better? These variables should have the entire value of the field, or not?

Comment: It is best if you give as much information as possible. For example, where is this code of yours? Is it in some views template? If so, which template?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the spacing in the html itself? So the code looks visibly nested? Such as:

```
<div>
   <div>
      <div>
         something
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If that's the case, you might want to try a WYSIWYG and add [WYSIWYG CodeMagic](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_codemagic)